# Did/How did Dumbledore know that Black was innocent?

Tags: harry-potter

In Harry Potter and the Prisoner of Azkaban, Harry, Hermione and Dumbledore have a conversation.

> Dumbledore: [...]We have no chance of overturning Sirius' sentence.
>
> Harry and Hermione: *But you believe us.*
>
> Dumbledore: Yes, I do.

**Does this mean Dumbledore knew that Black was innocent? If he did, how did he know?**

Comment: This is not a duplicate of the linked question. That question, and its answers, discuss Sirius's original conviction, while this question is asking if in *Prisoner of Azkaban* Dumbledore knew that Sirius was innocent.

Comment: He only knew after the fact. The only people that knew that Sirius was innocent were Lilly, James (...they unfortunately couldn't testify), Wormtail, and Voldemort

Comment: [Related](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/83849/did-dumbledore-believe-that-sirius-black-betrayed-harrys-parents) (not dupe)...

Comment: maybe it was magic?

Answer (score 2):

### Not until the events of *Prisoner of Azkaban*.

As stated by user [I N T E R E S T I N G](/users/112267/i-n-t-e-r-e-s-t-i-n-g) in [his answer to a similar question](/a/213395/109642),  he couldn't possibly have believed that Sirius Black was innocent, because Albus Dumbledore had presented evidence that Sirius Black was the Potters' Secret Keeper:

> ‘There is not a shred of proof to support Black's story, except your word — and the word of two thirteen–year–old wizards will not convince anybody. A street full of eye-witnesses swore they saw Sirius murder Pettigrew. I myself gave evidence to the Ministry that Sirius had been the Potters' Secret Keeper.’
>   <sub>Harry Potter and the Prisoner of Azkaban - chapter 21 - page 287</sub>

He's only sure that Sirius Black is innocent after the three trustworthy protagonists say as such:

> ‘Sirius has not acted like an innocent man. The attack on the Fat Lady — entering Gryffindor Tower with a knife — without Pettigrew, alive or dead, we have no chance of overturning Sirius' sentence.’
> ‘*But you believe us.’*
> ‘Yes, I do,’ said Dumbledore quietly.
>   <sub>Harry Potter and the Prisoner of Azkaban - chapter 21 - page 287</sub>

It's quite possible, however, that Albus Dumbledore had his suspicions before then (relevant question: [Why did Dumbledore believe Sirius' version of events in PoA?](/q/82362/109642)).